# Finding the corresponding probabilities for the position of a random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have the following probability statement for the event $B$:

$$P(B) = 1 - \frac{P(S_{a+b} = b - a - 2)}{P(S_{a+b} = a - b)}$$

where $S_{n}$ is a simple random walk with the corresponding probabilities:

$$P(\text{moving up 1}) = \frac{1}{2}\text{ and }P(\text{moving down 1}) = \frac{1}{2}$$

I cannot figure out what the probabilities are in the probability statement, unfortunately.

I have considered a general case where we want to find, for example, $P(S_{n} = x)$ for a simple random walk, and I concluded this:

If $S_{n} = x$, then let $a$ be the number of positive steps and $b$ the number of negative steps. Then, $a + b = n$ and $a - b = x$.

Well, that would mean $a = \frac{n+x}{2}$ and $b = \frac{n-x}{2}$. So, $P(S_{n} = x) = {n\choose\frac{n+x}{2}} 2^{-n}$.

Comment: @Dole Yes, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about it, note that $X=2(Bern(p))-1$

Therefore
$$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^k X_k =\sum_{n=1}^k 2(Bern(p))-1=-k+2\sum_{n=1}^k (Bern(p))$$
$$=-k+2Binom(k,p)$$

Then
$$P(S_k=a)=P(-k+2Binom(k,p)=a)=P(Binom(k,p)=\frac{a+k}{2})$$

Therefore,
$$P(S_{a+b}=b-a-2)=P(Binom(a+b,p)=b-1)$$
$$P(S_{a+b}=a-b)=P(Binom(a+b,p)=a)$$

And you should be able to finish from here...

Comment: You are a savior and a lord! Thanks